Is leaving a fake positive review considered lying?
If I leave a positive review on a site for a friend whose company I never actually worked with, but it’s vague enough that’s it’s technically true (such as “this is a great and effective team”), is that lying?
In other words, by leaving such a review, on the one hand it’s true because you know and believe the company is great, but on the other hand the fact that you’re saying it on this site implies you actually worked with them so is that lying or Geneivat Daat or something?
Edit: or alternatively, and this is really the main case, that you’ve worked with the company but never used their service, so if I write “was great working with them”, is it geneivat daat since people will understand that as meaning I used their service?

If you aren't trying to mislead people, you surely wouldn't mind stating explicitly that you haven't worked with them but believe it to be true anyway because xyz
